# String to Bitmap in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and I can't seem to work this one out. I get a base64String and I need an image.

I did:

```
val imageBytes = string.toByteArray(). // string is the base64image
val image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.size)
```

Problem is that when I try to access the `image` , I get a `SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream returned null` message in the log. I wanted to use it inside a method with a return but it kept crashing on `return image`.

**How do I convert it correctly?**

I have checked and string is not empty, imageBytes has content and imageBytes.size is over 60000. The same string I use in swift and it converts image without any modifications, so I am confident the string is not the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
val imageBytes = Base64.decode(string, 0)
val image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.size)
```

That is all. You just have to decode the base 64 string first into a byte array.

Comment: Take care, this solution only work on kotlin-jvm. It doesn't work on kotlin-js or native ;)

Comment: @ValentinMichalak solution?

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
try {
  val imageBytes =Base64.decode(string,0);
  val image=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.size);
 return image;
} catch(Exception e) {
      e.getMessage();
      return null;
   }
```